# Crear un "option" con el atributo "hidden selected" con JS

Tags: javascript, css

Creé un select con sus opciones usando js, porque necesitaba crearlo de esta manera para insertarlo en una web a través de un editor de js incorporado. Y aunque salió "bien", necesito que tenga una leyenda inicial, como un "placeholder", al cargar la página. Buscando, encontré que funciona muy bien tener una opción "hidden selected", que no permite ser seleccionada pero se muestra al cargar.
¿Cómo creo esa opción a través de JS? No se como darle esos atributos.
Pongo en link de un codepen para que se vea mejor el código.

https://codepen.io/DKuper/pen/KKvxJyJ

Gracias!

```js
let select = document.createElement("select");
select.id = "select";
select.setAttribute("onchange", "javascript:location.href = this.value;");
select.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.selectedIndex = -1;");

let option1 = document.createElement("option");
option1.id = "es";
option1.setAttribute("value", "https://goodline.com.ar/");
let option1Texto = document.createTextNode("Español");
option1.appendChild(option1Texto);

let option2 = document.createElement("option");
option2.id = "en";
option2.setAttribute("value", "https://goodline.com.ar/en/");
let option2Texto = document.createTextNode("English");
option2.appendChild(option2Texto);

select.appendChild(option1);
select.appendChild(option2);

let header = document.getElementById("Top_bar");
header.appendChild(select);
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(5, 13, 66);
}

#Top_bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 30;
  background-color: rgb(5, 13, 66);
  height: 230px;
}

#select {
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(5, 13, 66);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgb(36, 46, 119);
  appearance: none;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 85%;
  width: 85px;
  z-index: 50;
}

#es {
  background-color: rgb(62, 195, 216);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#en {
  background-color: rgb(62, 195, 216);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="lang.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Top_bar"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con insertar en la primera opción un `option` con `value` vacío y agregarle los atributos `selected` y `hidden`.

```
let option1 = document.createElement("option");
option1.id = "idioma";
option1.setAttribute("value", "");
option1.setAttribute("selected", "true");
option1.setAttribute("hidden", "true");
let option1Texto = document.createTextNode("idioma");
option1.appendChild(option1Texto);
```

El código completo según tu ejemplo, quedaría así:

```js
let select = document.createElement("select");
select.id = "select";
select.setAttribute("onchange", "javascript:location.href = this.value;");
select.setAttribute("onfocus", "this.selectedIndex = -1;");

let option1 = document.createElement("option");
option1.id = "idioma";
option1.setAttribute("value", "");
option1.setAttribute("selected", "true");
option1.setAttribute("hidden", "true");
let option1Texto = document.createTextNode("idioma");
option1.appendChild(option1Texto);

let option2 = document.createElement("option");
option2.id = "es";
option2.setAttribute("value", "https://goodline.com.ar/");
let option2Texto = document.createTextNode("Español");
option2.appendChild(option2Texto);

let option3 = document.createElement("option");
option3.id = "en";
option3.setAttribute("value", "https://goodline.com.ar/en/");
let option3Texto = document.createTextNode("English");
option3.appendChild(option3Texto);

select.appendChild(option1);
select.appendChild(option2);
select.appendChild(option3);

let header = document.getElementById("Top_bar");
header.appendChild(select);
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(5, 13, 66);
}

#Top_bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 30;
  background-color: rgb(5, 13, 66);
  height: 230px;
}

#select {
  position: relative;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(5, 13, 66);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 25px rgb(36, 46, 119);
  appearance: none;
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-left: 85%;
  width: 85px;
  z-index: 50;
}

#es {
  background-color: rgb(62, 195, 216);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

#en {
  background-color: rgb(62, 195, 216);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="lang.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="Top_bar"></div>

</body>

</html>
```